# "Unsafe attachments" prompt in Outlook on outgoing mail

Tags: vba, email, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2007

Plenty of info on *incoming* unsafe attachments but I've yet to find one that addresses my query on outgoing Outlook items.

I'm running a script that's sending large volumes of emails over Outlook and ideally i'd like to let it chug away all weekend: however last time I tried it got stuck when Outlook gave a prompt asking if I was sure I wanted to send the message since it might contain attachments that were unsafe.

It's very inconsistent: probably one in a thousand emails causes this and it doesn't seem to have any relation to the extensions of the attachments; which are exclusively PDFs, Docx, rtf, xlsx, html, or images.

So I'm dying for a way to either suppress the message, or build in something into the macro to circumvent it entirely, but I've absolutely no idea where to start since (as I said) all the search hits I get are only applicable to incoming mail items.

Help?!

Thanks!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/829982/outlook-blocked-access-to-the-following-potentially-unsafe-attachment has information about editing registry settings in order to whitelist certain attachment types. If you're in an exchange environment, it might require assistance from your network administrator. This would hopefully prevent that message from coming up at all.

Comment: That looks promising - do you think it applies the same to outgoing messages? This seems to focus on incoming ones but I can imagine the underlying settings might be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects of sending emails in Outlook:

1. Outlook security prompts. "Security" in this context refers to the so-called "object model guard" that triggers security prompts and blocks access to certain features in an effort to prevent malicious programs from harvesting email addresses from Outlook data and using Outlook to propagate viruses and spam. Read more about that in the [Outlook "Object Model Guard" Security Issues for Developers](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=52) article.
2. ["Outlook blocked access to the following potentially unsafe attachments" message in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/829982/outlook-blocked-access-to-the-following-potentially-unsafe-attachment).

Comment: The second point doesn't really apply since (as before) it relates to incoming mail items, but the first link offers some nice workarounds: unfortunately because I'm in a corporate environment it looks like whatever I use will need to be implemented at a network administrator level.

Comment: As another thought - do you think I could add some kind of on-event trigger to Outlook that sends keys to dismiss the message?!